# Create java object from javascript within apigee api proxy: Class is not a function, it is object

Tags: java, javascript, apigee

from javascript within an Apigee API proxy the following works as expected:

```
var javaString = new java.lang.String("FooBar");    
throw "javaString: "+javaString;
```

but this doesn't:

```
var date = new java.util.Date();
throw "date: "+date;
```

and throws following exception when creating an object

```
TypeError: [JavaPackage java.util.Date] is not a function, it is object
```

i've tried lots of stuff from the Mozilla Rhino Scripting_Java page but with no luck

please someone explain how am I being stupid

Comment: I guess it threats a `String` not as object although it is in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are not being stupid. Due to requirements of the Edge environment, not all standard class types are allowed within JavaScript callouts.

Currently, these should be allowed:

```
java.lang.Object
java.lang.String
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Boolean
java.lang.Long
java.lang.Double
java.lang.Float
java.lang.Short
java.lang.Byte
java.lang.Number
java.util.HashMap
```

java.util.Date is not currently allowed.

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. I was hoping to use some javax.crypto stuff - presumably need to deploy a jar instead that references these, or can it still be done through JS (or not at all) ?

Comment: I don't believe you can deploy jars at all. Because proxies can be running lots of traffic on a single VM, especially in the Apigee Edge cloud (multi-tenant if you are using a free organization), there are significant restrictions to avoid potential memory/performance issues. All Java classes need to be whitelisted. If you are a paid customer, you should be able to create Java callouts (significantly more work for you, though).

Answer (score 1):

To address your original question about creating an object of type date, you can do plain old JavaScript such as:

```
new Date() // current date and time

new Date(milliseconds) // milliseconds since 1970/01/01

new Date(dateString)

new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```